# Error while calling amazon lex from aws lambda using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-lex

I have published a Lex bot and a Lambda function on the same region. I am trying to interact with Lex from Lambda using following code.

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('lex-runtime')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.post_text(
      botName='string',
      botAlias='string',
      userId='string',
      # sessionAttributes={
      #     'string': 'string'
      # },
      # requestAttributes={
      #     'string': 'string'
      # },
      inputText='entity list'
    )
    return response
```

While testing the code my lambda function is getting timed out. Kindly let me know if you need to know anything else.

Error Message:

```
"errorMessage": "2021-04-30T07:09:45.715Z <req_id> Task timed out after 183.10 seconds"
```

Comment: Is your lambda in a VPC?

Comment: yes it is in default VPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda in a VPC, including a default VPC, **does not have internet access**. Since your lambda in a default VPC, it will fail to connect to any `lex-runtime` AWS endpoint, resulting in a timeout.

Since lex [does not support VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/integrated-services-vpce-list.html), the only way for your lambda to access the `lex-runtime` is:

- **disassociated** your function from VPC. If you do this, your function will be able to connect to the internet, and subsequently to `lex-runtime`.
- create a [private subnet in a default VPC, and setup a NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet). Then place your function in the new subnet. This way your function will be able to connect to the internet using NAT.

More info is in:

- [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: It is giving following error now  "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PostText operation: User: <user> is not authorized to perform: lex:PostText on resource: <alias>"

Comment: @hR312 This is a new issue, not related to the question posted. Your function lacks permissions to access lex and perform `lex:PostText` on it. You have to update its execution role.

Comment: Thanks "AmazonLexFullAccess" policy will work?

Comment: @hR312 It should. Its overly permissive, bot for quick test should be ok. I would recommend making new question with current execution role, and detailed error messages if the new issue persists.

Comment: Sure man. Thanks, will do after the role type is changed by admin.